# How to read a txt file in a ftp location connected to my windows pc using a filepicker in c#

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, winui-3

Hi i am a second year student in software development from the Netherlands and i am creating a application that reads a txt file but when i try to open the txt file from a ftp server in a filepicker and read it with readalllines the file.path stays empty and the app crashes'.
[Image Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB31L.png) [Image Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvZ4l.png)

I used file.readalllines but the file.path stays empty.

```
 public async void filepicker()
{

    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>> dayDic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>>();

    counterDic.Clear();
    dayDic.Clear();
    var filePicker = App.MainWindow.CreateOpenFilePicker();
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".log");
    filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    var file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();


    if (file != null)
    {
        filePath = file.Path;



        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(file.Path))
        {
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code and the exception you get when the app crashes. Did you test the filepicker using a local file?

Comment: for local files it works fine.

Comment: How do you open this FTP server? FileOpenPicker probably doesn't support the paths that are returned by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code in the MainWindow?

```cs
private async void filepicker()
{
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>> dayDic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>>();

    counterDic.Clear();
    dayDic.Clear();
    var filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();

    var hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);

    WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(filePicker, hWnd);

    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".log");
    filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    var file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (file != null)
    {
        var filePath = file.Path;

        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(file.Path))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I can confirm that works with files in shared folders.